# Change CGridView htmlOptions of Yii

Tags: yii, cgridview

I would like to use data provider value in htmlOptions.
How I can change the style of row according to a value from data provider.

```
 array(
    'name'=>'type',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>'$data->type==1?"Deposit" : "Withdraw"',
    'filter'=>array(1=>'Deposit',2=>'Withdraw'), 
    'cssClassExpression'=> '$date->type==1' ?  "label label-info":"label label-success",
  ), 
  // where label label-info and label label-success is my css classes
```

$data->type is a flag and it has two value 1 and 2 , I need to use class of label-info if the value is 1 else I need to use class of label-success

Now it is taking the first class only but second class is not taking effect

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

htmlOptions has no access to $data, but cssClassExpression does...

Please check this blow link and change your value field.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/46787-cgridview-column-htmloptions-ifthen-expression/

Try this:

```
'cssClassExpression' => '$data->service->reservable==0 ? \'label label-info\' : \'label label-success\';',
```

Comment: I tried to do like this:'cssClassExpression'=>'$date->type==1' ? 'label label-info'  :  'label label-success',  but it is not working

Comment: kumar_v I updated the question and still not taking effect can you please check it ?